# Converting NSString to UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, facebook-graph-api

Is this the correct way to convert a  `NSString` to a `UIImage`?

I tried this code:

```
NSString *localPng = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"resume-1"
                                                     ofType:@"png"];   

NSData* data=[localPng dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"datas %@",data);

UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] init];
image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

NSLog(@"--------  %@",image);

[self uploadScoreToFaceBook:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Medina Score %d",score] uploadImage:image ];
```

But I am getting a null value in `image`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is initializing an image with a path as data, which does't work obviously. What you might want to do instead is this:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:localPng] retain];
```

You can skip the data part.

---

The complete code would be this:

```
NSString *localPng = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"resume-1" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:localPng] retain];
NSLog(@"%@", image);
[self uploadScoreToFaceBook:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Medina Score %d", score] uploadImage:image];
```

---

Be sure to release your image when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: Thank you  , one more problem  NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
     
    NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:imageData
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    NSLog(@"new string %@",newStr);
    
    
    [[FacebookHelper sharedFacebookHelper] updateStatus:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your score is %@ %@",score,newStr]];

Comment: i want to update image to Facebook , there score os updating but in image place it is showing (null)..

Comment: @user937945 do you have a file called `resume-1.png` inside your application bundle? Note that the iPhone's file system is ***case-sensitive***. Also, use `%d` or `%u` (depending on signedness) if `score` is an `int`. Use `%@` only with Objective-C objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to retain the image you can simply use

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"resume-1.png"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have name of the image then probably using following will help.

`[UIImage imageNamed:(NSString *)name]`

provide name of the image here and you will get image.